# Open chrome://extensions from web using link

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an chrome extension that might be disabled by the user. I want to create a link to the chrome://extensions menu in that case. It would be something like

```
<a href="chrome://extensions" target="_blank">Chrome extensions</a>
```

which is not allowed: *Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/*

Most of the solutions I have read imply the use of an extension (which for this use case will be disabled):

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'chrome://extensions'});
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Of course, I might be wrong... In that case, what could I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As that message clearly states, you aren't allowed to do that.

Comment: in any case how would that help if your extension is already disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There exist privileged URLs and they cannot be opened from web pages or the command line.