# Open a chrome:// URL from HTML anchor

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

When running my application in debug mode I would like to display an HTML anchor link that opens the `chrome://inspect` page (I can safely assume users are using Chrome).

I can construct a link like the following:

```
<a href="chrome://inspect">Open Chrome Dev Inspector</a>
```

When hovering over the link, it shows the expected URL in the Chrome status bar, but clicking it does nothing. If I right click and "open in a new window"  it just opens a blank page (`about:blank`).

When clicked, the following error is shown in the console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://inspect/
```

Is it possible to programmatically open `chrome://` URLs?

Comment: Chrome extensions can create tabs with such URLs via chrome.tabs.create().

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Yes you're right, I've added the error to the post. I'm guessing this probably isn't going to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open chrome://extensions from web using link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910562/open-chrome-extensions-from-web-using-link)